# Can I use different search_view_id for one act_window depended of view_mode in Odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

```
<record id="open_view_project_all" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Projects</field>
        <field name="res_model">project.project</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="domain">[]</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,form,gantt</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_project_project_filter"/>
        <field name="target">main</field>            
</record>
```

I want to use different search_view for the kanban and gantt view.
Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this really works, but I used something similar for simple view picking logic. I hope it will work for search_view as well.

```
<record id="open_view_project_all" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Projects</field>
    <field name="res_model">project.project</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,pivot,form</field>
    <field name="target">current</field>
    <field name="domain">[]</field>
    <field name="view_ids"
           eval="[(5, 0, 0),
                  (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'form', 'view_id': ref('your_tree_view')}),
                  (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'kanban', 'view_id': ref('your_kanban_view'), 'search_view_id': ref('your_search_view_kanban')}),
                  (0, 0, {'view_mode': 'gantt', 'view_id': ref('your_gantt_view'), 'search_view_id': ref('your_search_view_gantt')})]"
        />
    <field name="context">{}</field>
</record>
```